Psychological drama/horror based in apartment complex
I'm struggling to remember the name of a movie I had watched about 2 years ago.
The distinct pieces I remember from the plot are that it's quite a dark-toned movie, always night time or near dark. It's about a woman, living in an apartment complex and at the start of the movie the protagonist receives a suicide-scare call from her neighbor who is threatening to jump off the roof.
Other parts I remember are that the protagonist goes on a date with another occupant within the apartment complex.
At the end of the movie, I believe the plot twist, or psychological twist, is that the protagonist is actually the neighbor who called at the start, and turned out that it was the protagonist who actually committed suicide.
The movie is in color and was released some time after 2010, though I can't remember if it was based in America, or a foreign country. Memory tells me that the female protagonist had blonde hair.
Has anybody seen this movie that can remember the title?

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Thanks for the response @Paulie_D, I've updated to include a bit more information, unfortunately my mind escapes me when coming to think of any more detail.

Was it in English?

I believe so, if not English then possibly French.
